# how to perform a save operation with breeze and angular without using EF context

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Within my project I am trying to perform a save operation that updates my Breeze model as well as passes the updated object to my webAPI. In this project I am not using EF context as the project has been modeled to work with other interfaces. So within my webAPI class I have the following:

```
  [BreezeController]
    public class ReportLibraryApiController : ApiController
    {
       readonly long userid = 1;//testing
       readonly IReportLibraryManager manager = new ReportLibraryManager();//interface 

        //method for share
        [Route("reportlibrary/SetReportShare/")]
        [HttpPost]
        public DTOs.Report SetReportShare(JObject report )
        {
             //within here I plan to unwrap the JSobject and pull out the necessary 
             //fields that I need 
            DTOs.Report updatedreport=null;

            //manager.ShareReport(updatedreport.ReportId);
            //manager.UnShareReport(updatedreport.ReportId);
            return updatedreport;
        }
}
```

The Report Object looks like this

```
public class Report
{

    public Int64 ReportId { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string ReportDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportDateCreated { get; set; }
    public string ReportOwner { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReportLabel> ReportLabels { get; set; }
    public bool IsShared { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

From my angular service I am trying to call the save operation as:

```
app.factory('reportLibraryService',  function(breeze,  model){

        var serviceName = "reportlibrary/";

        var ds = new breeze.DataService({
            serviceName: serviceName,
            hasServerMetadata: false,
            useJsonp: true,

        });

        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: ds });

        model.initialize(manager.metadataStore);

        function returnResults(data){ return data.results}

        function setReportShare(report) {
           var option = new breeze.SaveOptions({ resourceName: 'SetReportShare' })
           return  manager.saveChanges(null, option).then(returnResults)
        };
}
```

I realize the return results may not be correct but at this point I am just trying to call the save operation in the API. When I run the code everything executes but the save/setting of the share does not fire. A secondary question is I'm still not clear on how the breeze model is updated? Am I supposed to issue a new query from the api and pass that back or is there a way to update the cached object. I'm new to breeze (obviously) and trying to figure out where to look.All the examples I have seen thus far use EF context to perform these actions. However in my case I don't have that option.

Should breeze be making the call or since I am not using EF should I be using `$http` directive to push the object up. then return a new object to breeze for binding? (that seems a little heavy to me and now how it is designed to work).
I'd appreciate any guidance, or information or how to figure this out.

Edited for more information...
Here is a little more detail based on some of the questions posted by Ward to my original question:

*where is your metadata that you code says is not on the server?*

The solution I am working on does not expose the EF context this far our. As a result interfaces have been created that handle the queries etc within the project. As a result I don't have the ability to use EF. Very similar to the Edmunds sample. I created a meta definition in the web project which references a report object I have defined. This class is much different from what is returned from the DB but it represents what the UI needs. I created two models

report.cs

public class Report
{

```
public Int64 ReportId { get; set; }
public string ReportName { get; set; }
public string ReportDescription { get; set; }
public DateTime? ReportDateCreated { get; set; }
public string ReportOwner { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<ReportLabel> ReportLabels { get; set; }
public bool IsShared { get; set; }
public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
```

}

model.js

```
app.factory('model', function () {

    var DT = breeze.DataType;
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    }

    function initialize(metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: "Report",
            namespace: "Inform.UI.DTOs",
            dataProperties: {
                reportId: { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
                reportName: { dataType: DT.String },
                reportDescription: { dataType: DT.String },
                reportDateCreated: { dataType: DT.String },
                reportOwner: { dataType: DT.String },
                reportLabels: { dataType: DT.Undefined },
                isShared: { dataType: DT.Bool },
                isFavorite: { dataType: DT.Bool }
            },
            navigationProperties: {
                labels: {
                    entityTypeName: "Label:#Inform.UI.DTOs", isScalar: false,
                    associationName: "Report_Labels"
                }
            }
        });
        metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: "ReportLabel",
            namespace: "Inform.UI.DTOs",
            dataProperties: {
                labelId: { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
                reportId: { dataType: DT.Int64 },
                labelName: { dataType: DT.String },
                isPublic: { dataType: DT.Bool },
                reports: { dataType: DT.Undefined }
            },
            navigationProperties: {
                labels: {
                    entityTypeName: "Report:#Inform.UI.DTOs", isScalar: false,
                    associationName: "Report_Labels", foreignKeyNames: ["reportId"]
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
```

*why are you configuring useJsonp = true ... and then POSTing to the SetReportShare endpoint?*

The dataservice was originally defined for GET requests for querying/returning results to the client. I reused the dataservice and tacked on the POST event. Based on your comment though I assume this is a no-no. In looking at the project I am working within the same domain (and always will be) so I don't really think I need jsonp as part of the dataservice definition. Am I wrong in thinking that? 
I gather from your question that I should have a separate dataservice for POST's and a separate one for GET's

*why is it returning the DTOs.Report type when you can tell by looking at the standard Breeze SaveChanges method that it returns a SaveResult?*

This was a typo on my part. The save Result was originally defined as just a JObject. My intent is to return (if necessary) an updated Report object. However I am unsure of the best practice here. If the client (breeze) is updating the cache object. Why do I need to return the report object. Would it not be better to just return a success fail result or boolean of some sort vs. returning an entire report object?

*why is your client-side saveChanges callback treating the response as if it came from a query?*

This is very simple as you stated, I have no idea what I am doing. I am certainly diving into the deep end as I don't have a choice right now... My question here is when you perform a CRUD operation are these not wrapped in a promise as when performing a query? Or is the promise only important for queries?

Thank you again-

-cheers

Comment: As I noted in my answer, if you insist on sidestepping EF right from the start, you should look at the [**NoDb**](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/net/NoDb) sample which strips things down to essentials. Load it. Play with it. Learn from it. I think it will really help you get on track.

Answer (score 1):

You're jumping into the deep end w/o knowing how to swim.

You haven't explained why you're going exotic. That's OK but you want to ease into it. I strongly recommend that you start with the "happy" path - Web API, EF, SQL Server - and then unwind them slowly as you start to understand what's going on.

If you can't do that, at least look at the [NoDb sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/net/NoDb) which doesn't use EF or SQL Server (see the [TodoRepository](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/NoDb/NoDb/Models/TodoRepository.cs)).

You absolutely can do what you're striving to do ... once you know how ... or find someone who does.

At this point, you've created nothing but questions. For example,

- where is your metadata that you code says is not on the server?
- why are you configuring `useJsonp = true` ... and then POSTing to the `SetReportShare` endpoint?
- why is it returning the `DTOs.Report` type when you can tell by looking at the standard Breeze `SaveChanges` method that it returns a `SaveResult`?
- why is your client-side `saveChanges` callback treating the response as if it came from a query?

As for your questions:

- the breeze model is updated automatically when the save completes
- no, you don't issue a new query from the api
- yes, you can (and usually do) return the server-updated object back in the `SaveResult`.
- $http (a method not a directive) is used by Breeze itself to communicate to the server; using it directly isn't going to change anything.

Not sure any of my answers help. But I do think you'll be fine if you take it from the top and work deliberately forward from one thing you understand to the next.

Comment: Thanks again, yes I am in the deep end and I know I am struggling. I've updated my post with some more detail. I appreciate your time and guidance.